# Configuration Ionic (Cordova) iOS APP distribution through AirWatch?

Tags: cordova, ionic3, airwatch

please, advice.
We have a iOS Ionic app (hybrid app = Cordova + Angular), signed by a certificate from the enterprise program because we need eploy In-house.

When I upload the application to a public space, and I install over link to IPA file, the application installs correctly.

When we try to distribute the application via AirWatch, it does not install.

Unfortunately, I do not have experience with the preparation applications for airwatch, so I would like to know:

1. Do I need to configure an iOS application (Ionic) and how?
2. Do I have to configure something in AirWatch?
3. Do I need to have an AirWatch SDK added?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If the installation via link works it must work also on AirWatch.

You don't need any additional step for AirWatch distribution. just an IPA signed for in-house distribution.